# Anaconda Idle - print pastes SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

[image]

I am very new to Python. I've bought a few books and I am eager to learn from my mistakes. However, this book doesn't include why this error pops up, even though I thought I did everything correctly. I pasted a picture in for you to follow my steps!

Comment: Instead of sharing an image of your code, please enter it in as plain text, clicking on the "{}" during entry/edit so that the support community can better analyze your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 or later. Used f-string.

```
print(f"Congratulations dumbass, you guessed the number in {count} tries!")
```